# EF multiple foreign key relationship on same primary key ApplicationUser table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to create a one-to-many relationship using EF 6 using a code-first approach.

Let's take simple and classical example. I have two entities `Invoice` and `UserApplication` which have a one-to-many relationship:

I also want to have an `UpdatedById` relationship with the same `ApplicationUser` table, to be able to show the names in the UI of who added the record and who modified it.

```
 public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
     public string FirstName { get; set; };
     public string  LastName { get; set; };
    }
     public virtual List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    
    
    
    public class Invoice
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Details { get; set; }
     public string CreatedById { get; set; }
     public string UpdatedById { get; set; }
    }
     public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    
     builder.Entity<Invoice>()
     .HasOne(f => f.CreatedBy)
     .WithMany(mu => mu.Invoices)
     .HasForeignKey(f => f.CreatedById);
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Navigation Properties on Application user for these relationships, you would need to create and configure seperate ones.

eg

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCore6Test
{

    public partial class ApplicationUser //: IdentityUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Invoice> InvoicesCreated { get; } = new HashSet<Invoice>();
        public virtual ICollection<Invoice> InvoicesLastUpdated { get; } = new HashSet<Invoice>();
    }
    
    public class Invoice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }
        public int UpdatedById { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser LastUpdatdBy { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Db: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
                        .HasOne(f => f.CreatedBy)
                        .WithMany(mu => mu.InvoicesCreated)
                        .HasForeignKey(f => f.CreatedById)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 

            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
                        .HasOne(f => f.LastUpdatdBy)
                        .WithMany(mu => mu.InvoicesLastUpdated)
                        .HasForeignKey(f => f.UpdatedById)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=efCore6Test;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true", o => o.UseRelationalNulls(true))
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                
                using var db = new Db();
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
               

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Or simply omit the Navigation Properties on Application User.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work as I expected, if it's not a bother for you, could you please make a short example of the whole scenario. Thank you.